# Outlining a photo for extrusion and point ascend in the z axis. How do I lock them to a 2D sketch?

Tags: 2d

I am tracing an image-background on blender to created a 2D shape that I will then extrude a few inches as a good starting point for my project. But when I accidentally changed the view angle I noticed this. Why are the points ascending towards me and how do I lock them to the x-y plane to get a simple 2D tracing?
I am having this problem with poly-build (making single point additions manually) and with the bezier tool when I subdivide it to create more curvature.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You were probably working in perspective mode while sketching.From that angle it's a little hard to tell, but:

- press numpad 7, see if everything is aligned fine
- (stay) in edit mode
- press A to select all
- press S -> Z -> 0
  that should fix it. 
   if not, please provide a screenshot from a different angle.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick